# 'RemoveDuplicates' method changes selection, not only Range object

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have a Range object which contains data from a unique column of a selection. I want to use the `RemoveDuplicates` method on this range object in order to get only unique values. My problem is: the selection on the worksheet is also being changed by the `RemoveDuplicates` method. I need only the range object to be changed. Here's my code:

```
Dim rngTst As Excel.Range
Set rngTst = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(65000, 1))
With rngTst
    .RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes  'remove duplicated values
End With
```

Comment: What is your end intention?  To use the data elsewhere?  If so, I would suggest using arrays.  I haven't done much with Range objects, but based on the microsoft documentation, a range object only refers to an area in a document and doesn't actually store the data from that area separately (found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835176.aspx)

Comment: If you need to keep track of something you shouldn't use `selection`. Use another `range` object.

Comment: There is something strange or missing in your post. It should not at all change the selection, unless the current selection is part of the affected range itself.

Comment: @BrandenKeck, my intention is to use the data on a loop but I need only unique values. Thanks.

Comment: @CarlosRabelo What do you mean by "I need only the range object to be changed"? As @BrandenKeck pointed out, a `range` object is basically just a reference to a range on your worksheet. You cannot perform an action on the data of your range object without affecting the data on your worksheet.

Comment: @Kyle Now I see that working with Ranges is trickier than I thought. I'll review my code. Thank you for the advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with all the comments to your question. The `Range` object isn't really suitable for your task. It's quite easy to think that some of the Excel functions can simply be reproduced in a macro, but in VBA there are usually better ways of doing it ... and avoiding `Activate`/`Select` is the first step in recognising VBA's versatility.

If you simply need to loop through a list of unique values and process them in some way, then a `Collection` object would be ideal for you because each key must be unique, and working away from the `Worksheet` will be vastly quicker for you.

Here's some code which shows how simple it is to take the values from the `Range` object and to create a unique list from them.

```
Dim uniques As Collection
Dim r As Long
Dim v As Variant

'Read the values
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'adjust to your sheet name
    v = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(65000, 1)).Value2
End With

'Populate the unique collection
Set uniques = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For r = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
    uniques.Add v(r, 1), CStr(v(r, 1))
Next
On Error GoTo 0

'Loop through your values
For Each v In uniques
    'do something with your values
    Debug.Print v
Next
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar to Collections so I haven't had this idea... I'll try this approach. Thank you so much.

Comment: your solution is just perfect. I managed to do the job using Collections. Many thanks to you and all who helped me.